# Does $\{nz^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge uniformly in the open unit disc of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, limits, uniform-convergence

Let $E$ be the open unit disc about the origin in $\mathbb{C}$.  Consider the sequence of functions $\{nz^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on $E$.

I'm trying to show that $\{nz^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$  converges 
pointwise on $E$, and then to investigate whether this convergence is uniform or not.

**Attempt to show that $\{nz^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges for every $z$ in $E$:**

1. Let $z \in E$ so that $|z| < 1$.
2. I claim that $nz^n \rightarrow  0$ under such a constraint.
3. Let $\varepsilon > 0$.
4. Consider that

   $$
   |nz^n - 0| = |nz^n| = n|z^n| = n |z|^n
   $$

   Now since $0 \le |z| < 1$, we have from real analysis that $|z|^n \rightarrow  0$.  We also have from real analysis/calculus that the real sequence $|z|^n$ tends faster to $0$ than $n$ tends to $\infty$, in the sense that $n |z|^n \rightarrow  0$.  (Equivalently, if instead $|z| > 1$ we have would that $\frac{n}{|z|^n} \rightarrow 0$).
5. It follows from the last step that -- for large enough $n$ -- we can make it so that $|nz^n - 0| < \varepsilon$, so that $nz^n \rightarrow 0$  as desired.

Is there an easy way to see the claim I make in (4) without handwaving?  Also, does this sequence of functions on $E$ uniformly converge and if so why?

Comment: For (4), you can rewrite your sequence and try L'Hopital.

Comment: For (4), note that if $n > \sqrt {|z|} / (1 - \sqrt {|z|})$, then $1+1/n < 1/\sqrt{|z|}$. So the ratio of consecutive terms is $(n+1)|z|^{n+1}/(n|z|^n) = |z|(1+1/n) < \sqrt {|z|}$, and the sequence tends to $0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequence of functions
$$f_n(z)=nz^n, \,\,\,n\in\mathbb N,
$$ 
DOES ΝΟΤ converge uniformly to $0$ in the open unit disc $D$ as
$$
f_n(z_n)=1, \quad\text{for}\,\,\, z_n=n^{-1/n}\in D,
$$
even worse
$$
f_n(z_n)=\frac{n}{2}, \quad\text{for}\,\,\, z_n=2^{-1/n}\in D.
$$
In fact
$$
\sup_{z\in D}\lvert\, f_n(z)\rvert=n,
$$
and therefore $f_n$ DOES NOT converge uniformly in the open unit disc. Note that if $f_n:X\to\mathbb C$ converges uniformly to $f$, then for every $x_n\to x$, then $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$.

On the other hand $f_n(z)=nz^n$ DOES converge uniformly to $0$ in any open disc $D_r$, $r<1$,
since
$$
\sup_{z\in D_r}\lvert f_n(z)\rvert=nr^r\to 0,
$$
as $n\to \infty$. This can be proved using for example ratio test for sequences.

Answer (score 1):

For 4., you can use the following:

> **Lemma.** If $\delta>0$, then $\frac{(1+\delta)^n}{n}\rightarrow\infty$ or, equivalently, $n(1+\delta)^{-1}\rightarrow 0$.

*Proof.* Let $n\geq 2$. By the Binomial Theorem,
$$\frac{(1+\delta)^n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\delta^n\geq\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{2}\delta^2=\frac{n-1}{2}\delta^2\rightarrow\infty.\mathbf{QED}$$

To see that $nz^n$ does not converge uniformly in $E$, you could simply notice that $nE^n\supseteq E$ for every $n$. I'm going to explain this further:

By contradiction, suppose that $nz^n$ converges uniformly in $E$. Since the uniform limit (if it exists) is equal to the pointwise limit, we would have $nz^n\rightarrow 0$ uniformly in $E$. Let $\varepsilon$ be **any** number $0<\varepsilon<1$. Then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\varepsilon^{1/n}\in E$ but $|n(\varepsilon^{1/n})^n-0|\geq \varepsilon$, and that contradicts the uniform convergence (we had to show this for some $\varepsilon$, but this actually holds for any $\varepsilon$, which is obviously stronger).

Therefore, $nz^n$ does not converge uniformly in $E$.

Comment: But converges uniformly on compacts.

Comment: @studiosus Exactly. This is immediate from the lemma, since only the absolute value matters for convergence to $0$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I made this comment because I thought that the OP was actually asked to prove uniform convergence on compacts.